# Get unknown exception while rewriting text file

Tags: c#, text-files, file-access

So I have a function call classifier that basically check all text file in a directory, if there is any text file contains more than 50 line of words, then classify that text file into a type using other class called Text_Classification which I am sure its correct and error free. After classification, I will need to clean that text file and write a "Lines" as a first new line on that text file (this is for other class, so dont bother :) ).
But I got an exception, which mean there is something wrong in the `try{}` block.

Any idea why?

```
static void classifer(object state) {
    Console.WriteLine("Time to check if any log need to be classified");
    string[] filename = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\server_test\log");
    foreach(string textfile_name in filename) {
        var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(textfile_name).Length;
        if(lineCount > 50) {
            Console.WriteLine("Start classifying 1 of the logs");
            Text_Classification classifier = new Text_Classification(textfile_name, 1);
            string type = classifier.passBack_type();  //this function passes back the type of the log(text file)
            Console.WriteLine(type);
            try {
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(textfile_name); //clean the text file
                tw.WriteLine(" ");
                tw.Close();
                TextWriter tw2 = new StreamWriter(textfile_name, true);  //append <Lines> as the first new line on the text file
                tw2.WriteLine("Lines");
                tw2.Close();
            }
            catch {
                Console.WriteLine("cant re-write txt");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please re-run this code without the try/catch so the debugger can catch the exception? or at least capture and write out the error in the catch block so we know what the error is. `catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }`

Comment: Right, my bad, i should capture the error, running it now...

Comment: It said the text file is being used by another process, I tried run the code with the function call, and it ran successfully....

Comment: So, you need to find where in your application that you're opening and forgetting to dispose of the file. It has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: is there any function that can force to close other process of using the file that i want access to? In case i am not able to catch that process in other application

Comment: You can not force another application / process to release it's handle on the file, short of killing the process.

Comment: the problem is that i am not sure which process is using my file....
I have look a couple times on my other class/function and cannot find any...

Comment: `Text_Classification` is probably opening and not closing the file. Need to see it's code.

Comment: @yamen: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Unlocker is a good tool to see which process is locking a file. It can kill the process for you too. http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/

Comment: @yamen  and caesey you are right, there is a filereader not being closed in that class. THanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, this line is the culprit:

```
Text_Classification classifier = new Text_Classification(textfile_name, 1);
```

The class `Text_Classification` is opening and not closing the file `textfile_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following

```
            File.WriteAllLines(textfile_name, new String[]{" "});
            File.AppendAllLines(textfile_name, new String[]{" Lines "});
```

Instead of

```
               try
                {
                    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(textfile_name); //clean the text file
                    tw.WriteLine(" ");
                    tw.Close();


                    TextWriter tw2 = new StreamWriter(textfile_name, true);  //append <Lines> as the first new line on the text file
                    tw2.WriteLine("Lines");
                    tw2.Close();
                }
                catch {
                    Console.WriteLine("cant re-write txt");
                }
```